# What is the difference between a folder and an archive?

Tags: directory, compression, gzip, tar, archive

I am learning about .tar.gz files while reading about the gzip utility. I read [here](https://linuxize.com/post/gzip-command-in-linux/) that tar utility is used only to create an archive and not for compression.

So why do we even need archives when they are same as directories? (A collection of files and folders.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that you can put a directory structure into a *single file*, which makes it possible to send it to someone or to save it. Then they or you can reconstruct the directory structure from that file.

Comment: Thanks... i was having trouble understanding that... but your answer cleared it all. I would Up vote if i could.. but i am new. Anyways, Thanks a lot

Comment: Isn't a directory still a file (based on Unix philosophy that everything is a file)? I still can't understand why we can't attach a folder to an email.

Comment: A directory is indeed a file in Unix, but it contains only the metadata for the contained objects, e.g. names, types, timestamps, permissions, etc. Not the data in those objects. You _can_ attach a folder to an email, which will result in a zip file being created in most email clients.